# Navigating to a workbook stored on Sharepoint via Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to manipulate an Excel workbook stored on our intranet Sharepoint server at

https://xyz.ourserver.com/sites/site/list/subdir/Test.xlsx

This is the API use I got so far (I guess / hope this can be done a lot easier, but currently I am just poking around):

```
var site = await graphClient
    .Sites["xyz.ourserver.com"]
    .SiteWithPath("sites/site")
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

var list = await graphClient
    .Sites[site.Id]
    .Lists["list"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

var driveItems = await graphClient
    .Sites[site.Id]
    .Lists[list.Id]
    .Drive
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath("/subdir")
    .Children
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Steps 1 + 2 (getting the site and the list) work OK, but step 3 throws "itemNotFound Message: The resource could not be found."

Of course I tried many variations of this. Also, this alternative Step 3 returns an empty collection:

```
var children = await graphClient
    .Sites[site.Id]
    .Lists[list.Id]
    .Drive
    .Root
    .Children
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

"subdir" definitely exists (so does test.xlsx). I am also quiet sure that the list is OK, it has the WebUrl property "https://xyz.ourserver.com/sites/site/list".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a permissioning problem. This became obvious, when I compared the (ok looking) Graph Explorer json result and the (empty) json result the application was receiving (which I inspected in Fiddler).

I used this Graph Tutorial (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-aspnetmvcapp) to explore the Graph API. The application permissions were already set up correctly, but I did not know that the PrivateSettings.config requires additional "ida:AppScopes" too (in my case: value="User.Read Calendars.Read Files.Read Files.ReadWrite Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite.All Sites.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All").

With those settings, this code works:

```
var drive = await graphClient
    .Sites["rwe.sharepoint.com"]
    .SiteWithPath("sites/site")
    .Lists["list"]
    .Drive
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

var driveItems = await graphClient
    .Drives[drive.Id]
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath("subdir")
    .Children
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```